# Workaround for 'magick display' on Mac

Tags: macos, imagemagick, display

I have installed imagemagick @7 using 'brew' on a Big Sur Mac. The 'display' option gives an error "display: delegate library support not built-in (X11)".

This is not a mystery. The solution used to be to install imagemagick with some -with-X11 option. This option has gone from the latest 'brew' builds. It may be back someday, but I understand the X11 support was problematic. If this is so, then building from source sounds tricky.

I can convert my weird format files to another format, and open them in some compatible viewer. I want to look at floating-point files without worrying that the values may have been clipped by format conversion. I might use python matplotlib. But is there a neater way?

Following from the comments, I installed 'xquartz' and built ImageMagick 7.0.10 from source. My current version was done with ./configure --with-modules (this is probably not needed for what I wanted). The configure reports showed that the X11 libraries were found and linked. 'make check' passed. The environment variable DISPLAY is set to :0. But if I try to display an image with (for example)...

> magick display logo.gif
> ...I get...
> display: unable to open X server `:0' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/412.

This is progress: it is trying to connect but isn't managing it. I find lots of possible solutions from about 2018, but nothing on version 7 (which I need) on Big Sur.

ImageMagic display now works for me. I rebooted the Mac (may not have been necessary but someone advised this). I deleted the export DISPLAY=":0" - this was a relic from earlier experiments. I run Xquartz, which sets up the Display to something long and complicated, and as long as XQuartz is running, commands work from any terminal. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Write the data to disk, and use the `open` utility to "display". It's pretty easy to associate the default application to a file type. [Hex Fiend](https://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) is pretty good for raw binary.

Comment: Install XQuartz. See https://www.xquartz.org

Comment: Try `xclock` first and see if the basic XQuartz server is working - independently of ImageMagick. Your `DISPLAY` environment variable looks suspicious - how did it get set? Mine is `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.086Ppo9AM7/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`

Comment: Yes. This was a relic from some earlier experiments. I got rid of this and everything is now working.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of **homebrew** have dropped support for X11 using the `--with-X11` option to **ImageMagick**. That means you cannot readily use commands like the following that display an image directly without having to save it to disk and open some non-ImageMagick viewer:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:red display:
```

However, you can use macOS's built-in **Image Preview** in a very analogous way, by adding your own *"delegate"*. Just create a file with these contents:

```
<delegate decode="png" encode="display" spawn="True" command="magick %i %u.png && /usr/bin/open -a Preview %u.png"/>
```

and save it as `$HOME/.config/ImageMagick/delegates.xml` That tells **ImageMagick** that when you put `display:` at the end of the command, it should take the current image, make a temporary PNG version of it and use the **Preview** app to display it.

Now, whenever you want to view the output of an **ImageMagick** command just use:

```
magick INPUTIMAGE ... processing ... display:
```

Comment: Mark, you should mention that there is XQuartz to replace X11 and be able to use display: without your alternate method

Comment: @fmw42 Hi Fred. The point I am trying to make is that, if you install **ImageMagick** via **homebrew**, you cannot link it with X11 any more so even if you have **XQuartz** installed, it will not work - per the first line of OP's question. **homebrew** ships **ImageMagick** *without the ability to interact with anything X11* at all, and there is no easy way to enable it - short of doing a custom build using `./configure` and `make` and all that jazz.

Comment: `Mark Setchell` Thanks for the update Mark.  That makes it much more clear.